# Не осуществляется метод destroy. Ruby on rails

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails

В контроллере прописал метод  destroy

```
def destroy
    binding.irb
    @twit = load_twit
    @twit.destroy
    redirect_to twits_path
  end
```

После чего во views в show добавил кнопку осуществляющую соответствующее действие

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", twit_path(@twit), :class=>'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Однако, когда пытаюсь удалить пост ничего не происходит.
Попробовал также создать в консоли новый пост и удалить его, но ситуация такая же

Comment: То есть, после удаления вы в консоли ищете твит с таким айдишником, и он находится? И никаких ошибок нет при этом? В модели метод destroy не переопределён, случайно?

Comment: помогло добавление turbo-method .

Comment: Ну да, 7-е рельсы такие рельсы...

Comment: вот с удалением разобрался, а вот комментарии не добавляются. проверил через binding.pry, метод build работает, но комментарии не отображаются. как могу исправить ?

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос, добавьте в него соответствующий код контроллера и вьюхи и все детали проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Если используете rails 7:

вместо

```
method: :delete
```

используйте

```
data: { "turbo-method": :delete }
```